# Wrap Text in Table / Text Extends Past Page Margins

Tags: tables, line-breaking, cv, textwidth, column-width

I would like to know who to wrap text in a table, and also to keep text from off the page of the document.  Below is the code I have written so far.

I am trying to wrap the text under 'Relevant Coursework' and keep the text from running off the document.  And also, 'Chicago, IL and Expected June 2020' are completely off of the page. How would I go about fixing this problem? I have provided a screenshot of the pdf  below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfULg.jpg

Code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
% or \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in} % -.5in
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in} % -0.5in
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
\vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule          \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
\item\small{
\textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingEd}[6]{
\vspace{-1pt}\item
\begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
    \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \textbf{\small#5} \small#6  
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
\vspace{-1pt}\item
\begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
  \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\href{}{\Huge John J. Doe}} & Email :   \href{mailto:xxxxx@gmail.com}{xxxxx@gmail.com}\\
\href{}{} & Mobile : +1-312-xxx-xxxx \\
\href{}{} & Address : xxx x xxxxx xxxxx \\
\href{}{} & Chicago, IL. 60601
\end{tabular*}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
\resumeSubheadingEd
  {University of Chicago}{Chicago, IL}{Master of Science in Computer Science,  GPA: 3.8 / 4.0}{Expected June 2020}{Relevant Coursework:}{Machine Learning, Data Management Systems, Data Mining, Build and Implement Financial Engines, Regression Analysis, Time Series Analysis, Quantitative Analysis}

\resumeSubheadingEd
  {Booth Graduate School of Business – University of Chicago}{Chicago, IL}{M.B.A in Finance,  GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}{Graduated June 2018}{}

\resumeSubheading
  {Northwestern University}{Chicago, IL}
  {Bachelor of Science in Finance, GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}{Graduated August 2015}

\resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a p column instead of an l columns will allow the content of the column to line break:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
% or \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in} % -.5in
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in} % -0.5in
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
\vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule          \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
\item\small{
\textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheadingEd}[6]{
\vspace{-1pt}\item
\begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{p{0.8\linewidth}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
    \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
    \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \textbf{\small#5} \small#6  
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
\vspace{-1pt}\item
\begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
  \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\href{}{\Huge John J. Doe}} & Email :   \href{mailto:xxxxx@gmail.com}{xxxxx@gmail.com}\\
\href{}{} & Mobile : +1-312-xxx-xxxx \\
\href{}{} & Address : xxx x xxxxx xxxxx \\
\href{}{} & Chicago, IL. 60601
\end{tabular*}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
\resumeSubheadingEd
  {University of Chicago}{Chicago, IL}{Master of Science in Computer Science,  GPA: 3.8 / 4.0}{Expected June 2020}{Relevant Coursework:}{Machine Learning, Data Management Systems, Data Mining, Build and Implement Financial Engines, Regression Analysis, Time Series Analysis, Quantitative Analysis}

\resumeSubheadingEd
  {Booth Graduate School of Business – University of Chicago}{Chicago, IL}{M.B.A in Finance,  GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}{Graduated June 2018}{}

\resumeSubheading
  {Northwestern University}{Chicago, IL}
  {Bachelor of Science in Finance, GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}{Graduated August 2015}

\resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you much.

Comment: Two more quick questions if you don't mind. What value should I adjust to get the relevant coursework line to extend to the right to run under " Expected June 2020"?

Comment: And what value should I adjust to align my contact information at the top so that it aligns with the right margins? It seems slightly off.

Comment: @Richard For new questions better ask new questions